# distance based ordering in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, orm

So i am using django and get user's location at registration time.

Then i show these users on the front page of the app but sorted as per the distance, i.e, the closest ones to the logged in user are on the top and so on.

Now what i am doing is i am ordering them as per distance on the backend using some annotate (etc) functions provided by django ORM.

```
sortedQueryset = self.get_queryset().annotate(distance=Distance(
                'coords', user.coords, spheroid=True)).order_by('distance')
```

Where `'coords'` is the column in db to store the point (location), `user.coords` is point (coordinates) of the logged in user.

Now to get only first 100 users (say) from the database i can do something like this;

```
sortedQueryset = self.get_queryset().annotate(distance=Distance(
                'coords', user.coords, spheroid=True)).order_by('distance')[:100]
```

But what it think, it still grabs all the rows, orders them as per distance and then gets 100 of them. Say we have a million users in db, then it always has to get all those and then sort them and then get only 100.

I think it is a lot of overwork (maybe i am wrong or maybe this is the only way as i have to sort as per distance and that also depends on the logged in user, who is closest and who is farthest).

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken user.coords change every time, when user changed. So In django level you way is fastest that I know. But If you want more performance use Postgres GIS, or search engine ( Elasticsearch ).

Comment: @JavohirElmurodov absolutely right. user.coords change with different users as it is the coordinates of the current logged in user (means different devices simply). I am using postGIS (as i mentioned point instead of coordinates which is provided by GIS), But i don't know about ElasticSearch. Can you please explain a bit how to use this in my case.

Comment: In postgresql, more data means less performance. But Elasticsearch more stable for more datas. You can check djagno elasticsearch docs. https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: you can use elascticsearch and note that `Generally, slicing a QuerySet returns a new QuerySet – it doesn’t evaluate the query. An exception is if you use the “step” parameter of Python slice syntax.` read more here :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Comment: I think it is should be great if use Geo Distance Query of elastic search.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html#query-dsl-geo-distance-query

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow for now, i am not using step parameter as i am just getting the first 10 or 100 (say) users, does that mean i am going right for now??

Comment: from the documentation as i wrote before it is fine but if you want also you can cache the response.

Comment: I am caching the response on the front end (using redux) but i thought this may be a problem, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you have done is right only. This will not slice in Python but limit it in the database query itself. So it won't get all the results and slice it, instead, it runs **LIMIT** query against the database. See the documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow mentioned it in the comment. Marking your answer as accepted